# C# - variable modifiable from only one method

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

Is there a way to have a variable avaliable for reading from anywhere but modifiable from only one method in a class?

For example

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int IntegerA;

    public ClassA(){}

    public void MethodA()
    {
        //should work in this method
        IntegerA=100;
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        //shouldn't work here
        IntegerA=100;
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public void MethodC()
    {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();

        //should be readable
        int b=classA.IntegerA;

        //modifying shouldn't work here as well
        classA.IntegerA=100;
    }
}
```

I tried creating additional class containing only IntegerA and MethodA and it kinda works but MethodA also uses some private variables from ClassA so it would be better to make it all one class.

Comment: No.  The owning class is trusted.  You're expected to know better.  Perhaps you should call the variable `_IntegerA` and make it private, and create an `IntegerA` property with a getter but no setter.  Now everyone can read `IntegerA`, but only functions in the class can write to `_IntegerA`.

Comment: Try `public int IntegerA { get; private set; }`

Comment: If you declare a read-only property like `public int IntegerA { get; private set; }`, then it will be readable and writable anywhere within its defining class (`ClassA`), but only readable outside of that class.  That's as good as you are going to get

Comment: You can write Roslyn analyzer that will check where the variable/property is used.

Comment: As others already said, there is no such access control mechanism in C#. Probably the nearest one for you is a property with public getter and private setter.

Comment: I would suggest you to read basics of Object Oriented Programming and C#, else you will further get confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the variable to be changed only by one method, you must make a class of abstract(BaseClass) type and the main class will inherit from it.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public int IntegerA { get; private set; }
        public BaseClass() { }

        public void MethodA()
        {
            //should work in this method
            IntegerA = 100;  
        }
    }
```

ClassA

```
 public class ClassA : BaseClass
    {
        public ClassA() { }
        public void MethodB()
        {
            //should work in this method
            var b = IntegerA;
            //shouldn't work here
            IntegerA = 10;//error
        }
    }
```

If you want the variable to be changed only by  methods inside class, you must  change access type , can read inside or outside class this variable

```
 public int IntegerA { get; private set; }
```